# How to change Federated MySQL storage engine to supported

Tags: mysql, federated-storage-engine

I need to create view with different schemas, one is in local and other in remotely. For that I created a server instance by the below statement.

```
CREATE SERVER diary
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (HOST '192.168.0.124', PORT 3306, DATABASE 'diary_org2');
```

And it was successfully excecuted. Then I tried to create a federated table by the below query

```
CREATE TABLE `role` (
  `ROLE_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ROLE_NAME` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `IS_DELETE` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `DATE_TIME` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ROLE_ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ROLE_NAME_UNIQUE` (`ROLE_NAME`)
) 
ENGINE=FEDERATED
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
CONNECTION='diary/role';
```

But it was not excetued, it shows unkown engine name 'FEDERATED'.
Then I list the mysql engines, and it shows federaed as not supported.

[image: Storage engines]

**Edit:**
    I also added federated in my.ini file in the ProgramData, and restarted mySQL, bt Federated engine is not supported.

and Err log shows

```
2016-09-29 16:09:36 1280 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-09-29 16:09:36 510 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
```

Comment: @Shadow I tried this too

Comment: @Shadow lookup my updates

Comment: It's the same: you have not enabled the federated storage engine, therefore in the log MySQL notes (it is not an error) that this storage engine is disabled. You need to follow the instructions in the duplicate topic to enable the storage engine.